# In SQL Server, can I set a foreign key on a column that does not exist?

Tags: sql-server, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I am using SQL Server 2005, and I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Workflow]
(
    [WorkflowId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](1000) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application]
(
    [ApplicationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rel_Workflow_Application]
(
    [WorkflowId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

The rule is that in `Rel_Workflow_Application`, `ApplicationId` must exist in the `Application` table or it can be 0. I don't have a record in table `Application` where `ApplicationId = 0` and I don't wish to create one.

How can I set this constraint?

Comment: Why not `NULL` instead of `0`. Also foreign key will never let you to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is possible to use the `NOCHECK` when creating a foreign key, this is a hack that might prove problematic.  I would use null instead of 0 and if 0 needs to show up in queries use `coalesce(ApplicationID, 0)` in the select statements or create a view which does this and query that view instead.

This cleanly indicates that the foreign key does not have a row in `Application`.

Comment: Using NULL instead of 0 is the way to go.